# How do I get type names into static_assert errors?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, static-assert

Assume I have this program, in which I want a bunch of specialized types and no general type. When I compile it, I'd like to get `"Error: Int"` instead of `"Error: Z"`. I've tried `typeof(Z)` and that didn't get me anything - is there a standard trick to this?

```
template<class Z>
Z derp()
{
    static_assert(false, "Error: Z");
}

template <>
double derp<double>()
{
    return 5;
}


int main()
{
    double b = derp<double>();
    int r = derp<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required on account of that static assertion violating [[temp.res]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8). But that is easily fixable. We can just define the primary template as deleted:

```
template<class Z>
Z derp() = delete;

template<>
double derp<double>()
{
    return 5;
}


int main()
{
    double b = derp<double>();
    int r = derp<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Now the program is well formed, unless the primary specialization is actually called. Most compilers will also give the error message you want. Here's Clang 5.0:

```
prog.cc:14:13: error: call to deleted function 'derp'
    int r = derp<int>();
            ^~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:2:3: note: candidate function [with Z = int] has been explicitly deleted
Z derp() = delete;
  ^
```